# Matplotlib : the colorbar keeps shrinking

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I wrote a code where I have an array called `array2` with numbers between `0.` and `1.` in it. When I click on the array displayed by `imshow` the cells in the array take the value `2.` and become red.

Then I added a colorbar but it kept shrinking once I clicked on it and the cells didn't become red.

What am I doing wrong ?

#### Code without colorbar (works fine)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from random import random


def test(n):
    array1 = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            array1[i,j] = random()
    return array1


# Array
global array2
array2 = test(10)


# Colormap
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)
colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)


# Matplotlib
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.imshow(array2, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5, origin='lower')


def onclick(event):
    global x, y
    x, y = int(event.xdata), int(event.ydata)
    array2[y,x] = 2.

    plt.imshow(array2, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5, origin='lower')


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

[image]

#### Code with colorbar (doesn't work)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from random import random 


def test(n):
    array1 = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            array1[i,j] = random()
    return array1


# Array
global array2
array2 = test(10)


# Colormap
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)
colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)


# Matplotlib
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1)
fig.tight_layout()

im = plt.imshow(array2, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5, origin='lower')

divider = make_axes_locatable(axes)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="13%", pad=0.2)

cb = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, boundaries=np.linspace(0,1, num=100), ticks=[0,1])

cb.set_label("Title", fontsize=15, labelpad=-5, y=0.5)

def onclick(event):
    global x, y
    x, y = int(event.xdata), int(event.ydata)
    array2[y,x] = 2.

    im = plt.imshow(array2, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5, origin='lower')

    divider = make_axes_locatable(axes)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="13%", pad=0.2)

    cb = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, boundaries=np.linspace(0,1, num=100), ticks=[0,1])

    cb.set_label("Title", fontsize=15, labelpad=-5, y=0.5)  


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

[image]

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Yes sorry I am edditing my question right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to just update the `imshow`, instead of drawing a new one every time a click is performed. This can be done using the `.set_data()` method. The advantage is that the colorbar can stay where it is and doesn't get touched.

In general it's best to work with the plotting objects directly instead of pyplot when doing interactive stuff. So using `fig` and `ax` instead of `plt` in most cases.

Note that to accurately catch the click on a pixel you need to round the coordinate first, `int(np.round(event.xdata))`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

global array2
array2 = np.random.rand(10,10)

# Colormap
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)
colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

# Matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.tight_layout()
im = ax.imshow(array2, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", 
               vmin=0, vmax=3.5, origin='lower')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="13%", pad=0.2)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax =ax, cax=cax, boundaries=np.linspace(0,1, num=100), 
                  ticks=[0,1])
cb.set_label("Title", fontsize=15, labelpad=-5, y=0.5)

def onclick(event):
    x, y = int(np.round(event.xdata)), int(np.round(event.ydata))
    array2[y,x] = 2.
    im.set_data(array2)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()  

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```